# Can I do better than CompressionLevel="high"?

Tags: wix, compression

I have a very simple installer - it is installing a single application binary and that's about it. The size of the binary is about 2.7MB. My MSI compiled with WiX is about 2.1MB. An equivalent installer made with InnoSetup is about 1.2MB.

I have `CompressionLevel="high"` in my `Media` element, is there any way I can do better than this, or otherwise reduce the size of my installer package? I'm rather concerned that the msi installer is nearly twice the size of our InnoSetup installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the best compression level you can get for a cabinet. What some people do is create an uncompressed installer and use a self-extractor or bootstrapper that uses LZMA for compression (like Inno Setup uses).